# Sales Cadence Missing from App Menu in High Velocity Sales

Tags: high-velocity-sales, sales-cadence

I am attempting to find the "Sales Cadence" tab in the High Velocity Sales app.

I have checked and my user has the [required permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=hvs_cadences_create.htm&type=5):

- High Velocity Sales Cadence Creator

I checked the Lightning App Manager for High Velocity Sales, and the app is there, but it does not appear in the navigation menu? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: The default setting for High Velocity Sales is to have "Sales Cadence" and "Work Queue" is to have the tab's hidden. Adjusting this in the profile solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default Salesforce High Velocity Sales (HVS) sets the Work Queue, Sales Cadences, Call Scripts and High Velocity Sales Performance tabs to hidden. There are two options to make these visible to users.

1. Make adjustment to profile(s). Go to the profile(s) you want to see these tabs. Go to object settings, then Work Queue. Set the Tab Settings to Default On. Repeat for the other HVS objects.

OR

2. Create a new permission set. Assign the permission set to the Salesforce license. Go to object settings, then Work Queue. Set the Tab Settings to Available and Visible. Repeat for the other HVS objects.

If you still can't view these tabs ensure

- The user has the High Velocity Sales User or High Velocity Sales Cadence Creator permission set assigned to them
- The tabs are available as a Navigation Item in the HVS App.